# Custom matplotlib discrete colormap with fixed values on raster

Tags: raster, color-ramp, matplotlib, colormap

I've been using a color ramp with fixed values (0-255) corresponding to specific rgb color (discrete interpolation) for 8bit tifs in QGIS. I've used matplotlib to apply built in colormaps, but I'm trying to figure out how to create a matplotlib custom colormap to replicate the results I get from QGIS that uses this fixed scale.

Example fixed value color ramp

```
# QGIS Generated Color Map Export File
# val, r, g, b, a, label
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
133,178,178,178,255,1
138,0,120,120,255,2
142,0,190,190,255,3 
... and so on
```

Any pointers on how to go about this? I was able to get fairly close with gdaldem color-relief but its interpolation is adjusting some of the values where it isn't quite as good as what QGIS is outputting... I'm assuming because its automatically using linear interpolation vs discrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got a custom matplotlib colormap figured out, but I did get gdaldem working to produce the required output by using -nearest_color_entry and -alpha options.

```
gdaldem color-relief -nearest_color_entry -alpha -of PNG input.tif colors.txt output.png
```

colors.txt was structured like this:

```
133 178 178 178 255
138 0 120 120 255
142 0 190 190 255
....
```

The main issue I had before was not using gdaldem with -alpha and the last column with alpha values.